# QLPreviewController identify markup mode

Tags: ios, swift, markup, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I have a custom `QLPreviewController` created to preview and edit the images in my app. I need to identify when the QLPreviewController enters markup mode, and based on that I have to show/hide some buttons on the navigation bar. But I cant find any way to identify this transition. The button action and UI changes are happening inside QLPreviewController and there is no delegate methods exposed by apple for this.

[image]

Another thing I tried was to check if pencil kit is added on the `view.subViews`. But it is presented in some other way, so that we cant find it in subviews.

Please help me find a solution for this.